# Unable to find deployed app. "Parse App not found" error in parseapp.com app URL

Tags: parse-platform

Learning about Parse.com. I've deployed the initial code via the `parse` command-line about an hour ago. When I go to my app's URL, I get a "Parse App not found" 404 page.

Just created a new app and deployed it for debugging purposes. The name of the app is `oct15test`.

When I visit https://oct15test.parseapp.com/ I get: [image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did not setup the subdomain for the app. Go to `https://www.parse.com/apps/oct15test/edit#hosting` and pick a subdomain there, should work just fine after that.